# regex: how to capture some words but with only one or two spaces maximum between them

Tags: r, regex

I would need help with the following regex:
If I have something like

`word1 word2                  word3 word4                   1234.23,4`

I would like to capture `word1 word2`, `word3 word4` and the numbers. Number of words in groups can vary, and sometim the second capturing group is absent.

I tried the following regex:

`([\w\s-]+)\s{5,}([\w/ -]{0,100})\s+([\d,\.]+)`

but I get:

[image]

(python, here: https://regex101.com/).

I don't know how to define a regex pattern that says "some words but with only one or two spaces maximum between them".
I use `([\w/ -]{0,100})` for the second group because somethime the second group is not here.
Here is a working example in `R`:

```r
test <- c("word1 word2                  word3 word4                   1234.23,4",
          "word1 word2                                                1946.27,4")

library(stringr)

str_match(test,"([\\w\\s-]+)\\s+([\\w/ -]{0,100})\\s+([\\d,\\.]+)")


     [,1]                                                                   [,2]                                                    [,3] [,4]       
[1,] "word1 word2                  word3 word4                   1234.23,4" "word1 word2                  word3 word4             " ""   "1234.23,4"
[2,] "word1 word2                                                1946.27,4" "word1 word2                                          " ""   "1946.27,4"
```

I would like `word3 word4` to be in the third output column for the first line (second capturing group).

How should I proceed ?

Comment: It should be `"^(\\w+(?:\\s{1,2}\\w+)*)\\s+(.*?)\\s+(\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)*)$"`

Comment: You can split input with `\s{3,}` regex

Comment: `strsplit(test, '\\s{3,}')` as @anubhava suggested

Comment: Thanks! I actually was looking for the non capturing group, that I did not know, and solve a lot of similar issues. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the result to be a *character matrix* with the full matches in the first column and then more columns for each capture group, you can use your [`str_match`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.3.1/topics/str_match) approach with a regex like

```r
rx <- "^(\\w+(?:\\s{1,2}\\w+)*)\\s+(.*?)\\s+(\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)*)$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7yJuB4/1).

The main point here is the `\w+(?:\s{1,2}\w+)*` part that matches one or more word characters (`\w+`) and then zero or more repetitions (`*`) of one or two (`{1,2}`) whitespace (`\s`) + one or more word chars (`\w+`) sequences.

If you want to get a *list* of the same length as `test`, you can use [`strsplit`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strsplit) with a simple regex like `\s{3,}` that just matches three or more whitespaces. Note that you'd better use the [`stringr::str_split`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.3.1/topics/str_split) version with this pattern since it matches any Unicode whitespace chars with this shorthand character class by default.